# Freeradius REST send all attributes

Tags: rest, freeradius

Pretty simple question, that I cannot seem to find any documentation for. For the rest module on freeradius you can define your url's, data payloads ect. Is there a way to pass all request attributes to the rest module data?

I am asking this specifically for the accounting payloads that change with respect to request type (i.e connect/disconnect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done by default, set body to 'post' or 'json' and it'll send all attributes to the server.  This is documented: https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v4.0.x/raddb/mods-available/rest#L66

Comment: Ah I see, I did not interpret the documentation in that manner! Thanks for the help!